# Can't click on element with Horseman

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, phantomjs, node-horseman

I'm building an app that will have the ability to allow the user to create Google Alerts as RSS feed.

Just started with Horseman/PhantomJS, and the issue I'm having now on the webpage is to click on a menu to display options on the "Deliver to":

[image]

By accessing this page via browser and clicking on where your e-mail will appear, a small `div` with two options shall appear for you to select "RSS Feed". Via Horseman, I can't find a way to click it. I took screenshots after the `click()` to see it, but nothing. My code:

```
horseman
  .open('https://google.com/alerts')
  .type('input[type="text"]', this.name)
  .click('span[class="show_options"]')
  .screenshot('/home/gabriel/Desktop/ga-named.png')
  .wait(2000)
  .click('.delivery_select > div.jfk-select')
  .screenshot('/home/gabriel/Desktop/ga-deliver-to.png')
  .close()
```

Only `.click('.delivery_select > div.jfk-select')` doesn't work. Below the HTML of that specific region:

```
<div class="delivery_select">
  <div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button jfk-select" role="listbox" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" style="user-select: none;" aria-activedescendant=":8m">
    <div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-caption" id=":8m" role="option" aria-setsize="2" aria-posinset="1">myemail@foo.com</div>
    <div class="goog-inline-block goog-flat-menu-button-dropdown" aria-hidden="true">&nbsp;
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I've never used Horseman, but surely you'll be able to implement the solution yourself.*

Clicking in your script doesn't work because that drop-down is not listening to clicks:

[image]

Instead you can simulate mousedown:

```
// Click "Deliver to" dropdown
.evaluate(function(){
    var event = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents'); 
    event.initEvent ("mousedown", true, true);     

    document.querySelector('.delivery_select > div.jfk-select').dispatchEvent(event);
})
```

Comment: Yea, it seems that was the issue, there's no `click` event for such element. I didn't know I could check it, thank you. According to the rendered image, it worked and I see the option there's supposed to appear, although it isn't aligned, but I believe it's fine. Much appreciated, @Vaviloff

Answer (score 1):

i think the issue is that it cannot click with the given class, try with different id.
Check this how i use horseman for login.

```
router.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    //default urls is http://144.76.34.244:8080/magento/1.9/web/customer/account/login//
    var url_ = req.body.url;
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;
    if (url_.length > 0 && username.length > 0 && password.length > 0) {
        horseman
                .userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0')
                .open(url_)
                .type('input[name="login[username]"]', username)
                .type('input[name="login[password]"]', password)
                .click('[name="send"]')
                .wait(5000)
                .url()
                .then(function (url) {
                    if (url == config.URL) {
                        res.json({status: "200", msg: 'login successfull', url: url});
                    } else {
                        res.json({status: "200", msg: "login failed"});
                    }
                })
                .screenshot('big.png')
                .close();
    } else {
        res.json({status: "500", msg: "invalid fields"});
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not. And to make things harder, I found out that the `div` that is shown when clicking on the option is actually embedded via JS. In other words, before the click it doesn't exist, something I could probably easily click, even hidden.